# Query for average scores of all game results in a collection?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app stores game results that can have a final score in the range of -30 to +30 in a field called `score`. How do I query for the overall average of all the game results?

Comment: It's been a long time since you asked this question but I just posted an up-to-date answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Simple Solution

If you know the number of game results being written will be at most once per second, you can use Cloud Functions to update a separate document `average/score`. For each game result addition, if the document didn't exist, set a field called `count` to 1 and a field called `score` to the game score. If the document did exist, add `1` to the field called `count` and add the score to the field called `score`.

Now, to query for the average score, simply read `average/score` and divide `score` by `count`.

## Scalable Solution

If you suspect or know the number of game results being written will exceed once per second, you will need to apply a distributed counter style of the Simple Solution.

Your data model for the average document will use subcollections and look like:

```
// average/score
{
  "num_shards": NUM_SHARDS,
  "shards": [subcollection]
}

// average/score/shards/${NUM}
{
  "count": 115,
  "score": 1472
}
```

To make your update code more streamlined, you can initialize these shards first with:

```
// ref points to db.collection('average').doc('score')
function createAverageAggregate(ref, num_shards) {
    var batch = db.batch();

    // Initialize the counter document
    batch.set(ref, { num_shards: num_shards });

    // Initialize each shard with count=0
    for (let i = 0; i < num_shards; i++) {
        let shardRef = ref.collection('shards').doc(i.toString());
        batch.set(shardRef, { count: 0, count: 0 });
    }

    // Commit the write batch
    return batch.commit();
}
```

Updating the average aggregate in Cloud Functions is now as easy as:

```
// ref points to db.collection('average').doc('score')
function updateAverage(db, ref, num_shards) {
    // Select a shard of the counter at random
    const shard_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * num_shards).toString();
    const shard_ref = ref.collection('shards').doc(shard_id);

    // Update count in a transaction
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(shard_ref).then(doc => {
            const new_count = doc.data().count + 1;
            const new_score = doc.data().score + 1;
            t.update(shard_ref, { count: new_count, score: new_score });
        });
    });
}
```

Getting the average can then be done with:

```
// ref points to db.collection('average').doc('score')
function getAverage(ref) {
    // Sum the count and sum the score of each shard in the subcollection
    return ref.collection('shards').get().then(snapshot => {
        let total_count = 0;
        let total_score = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            total_count += doc.data().count;
            total_score += doc.data().score;
        });
        return total_score / total_count;
    });
}
```

The write rate you can achieve in this system is NUM_SHARDS per second, so plan accordingly. Note: You can start out small and increase the number of shards easily. Simply create a new version of `createAverageAggregate` to increase the number of shards by first initializing the new ones, then updating the num_shards setting to match. This should be automatically picked up by your `updateAverage` and `getAverage` functions.

Answer (score 0):

### November 2023 update

On Nov 8 2023 [Firebase announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/aggregate-with-sum-and-avg-in-firestore) the `AVG()` and `SUM` aggregation functions ([check the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#web-modular-api_4)).

**Web Modular API**:

```
const gameResultsCollection = collection(firestore, 'game-results');
const snapshot = await getAggregateFromServer(gameResultsCollection, {
  averageScore: average('score')
});

const { averageScore } = snapshot.data();
```

**Node.js**:

```
const gameResultsCollection = firestore.collection('game-results');
const snapshot = await gameResultsCollection.aggregate({
  averageScore: AggregateField.average('score'),
}).get();

const { averageScore } = snapshot.data();
```